# Does there always exist a measurable function between measurable subsets of same measure?

Tags: measure-theory

This is a just a curiosity question that randomly popped in my head.

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $A$ and $B$ be two measurable subsets of $X$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$. Do we know that there exists a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that $f(A)=B$?

I feel like the answer is no, but I wouldn't even know where to begin to address this question. I would like an answer to cover both cases of $A$ being finite or infinite, as I feel like a counter example for sets of infinite measure could be found easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb R$, and consider $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb R$ and the Cantor (ternary) set $C\subset[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$. Both $C$ and $\mathbb Q$ have measure zero, but you're not going to be able to make $f(\mathbb Q)=C$ for any function $f$ since $|C|>|\mathbb Q|$.

Comment: Well that was easy. Perhaps I should ask if there is a function in at least one direction?

Comment: Alternatively, let $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mu$ the counting measure. Then $\mu(\mathbb Q)=\mu(\mathbb R)=\infty$ and again there is no such function by cardinality.

Comment: Yes, there might always exist a function in one direction. I'm contemplating now...

Comment: For $\emptyset$ and a nonempty set of measure $0$ there's nothing in either direction.

Comment: So the revised question: given two sets $\emptyset\subsetneq A,B\subset X$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$, does there exist $f:X\to X$ measurable so that $f(A)=B$ or $f(B)=A$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a set of cardinality $> 2$ and $B = \{1,2\}$ disjoint from $A$.
Consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr M$ on $A \cup B$ consisting of sets $S_1 \cup S_2$ where $S_1$ is either $\emptyset$ or $A$ and $S_2$ is any subset of $B$.  Let $\mu(A) = 1$, $\mu(\{1\}) = \mu(\{2\}) = 1/2$.  There is no  function from $B$ onto $A$, and no measurable function from $A$ onto $B$.

More generally, take any case where $A$ has greater cardinality than $B$ but fewer measurable subsets.